# Postgres: Join two tables with a set of multiple conditions

Tags: postgresql, join, duplicates

I have a table that looks like
[image]

The query to create the same table:

```sql
with t as (
    select *
    from (
        (
            values ('james', '801xxxxxxx', 'james@gmail.com', 'ca', 'a'),
            ('robert', '714xxxxxxx', '', 'ca', 'a'),
            ('william', '', 'william@gmail.com', '', 'a'),
            ('maria', '1234567890', 'maria@gmail.com', '', 'a'),
            ('richard', '', 'richard@gmail.com', '', 'a'),
            ('', '', 'james@gmail.com', '', 'b'),
            ('maria', '1234567890', '', '', 'b'),
            ('robert', '', '', 'ca', 'b')
        )
    ) t (first_name, phone, email, state, "type")
), a_t as (
    select *
    from t
    where "type" = 'a'
), b_t as (
    select *
    from t
    where "type" = 'b'
)
select *
from t
```

How can I remove any duplicates between different `type`s by using three sets of rules.
The rules are to drop duplicates if:

1. `email`s are matches
2. `phone`s and `first_name`s are matched at the same time
3. `state`s and `first_name`s are matched at the same time.

The outcome should look like
[image]

I've tried different approaches. My latest approach was to create two tables, `a_t` and `b_t`. `a_t` is a table whose `type` is `a`. `b_t` is a table whose `type` is `b`.
Then I tried to use different types of joins to merge the two tables.

[EDIT 1]

To follow @topsail's advice, I tried the below and a few more others. None of them did not give what I wanted.

```sql
with t as (
select *
    from (
        (
            values ('james', '801xxxxxxx', 'james@gmail.com', 'ca', 'a'),
            ('robert', '714xxxxxxx', '', 'ca', 'a'),
            ('william', '', 'william@gmail.com', '', 'a'),
            ('maria', '1234567890', 'maria@gmail.com', '', 'a'),
            ('richard', '', 'richard@gmail.com', '', 'a'),
            ('', '', 'james@gmail.com', '', 'b'),
            ('maria', '1234567890', '', '', 'b'),
            ('robert', '', '', 'ca', 'b')
        )
    ) t (first_name, phone, email, state, "type")
),
dedupe_one as (
    select distinct on (email)
        first_name, phone, email, state, "type"
    from t
),
dedupe_two as (
    select distinct on (phone, first_name)
        first_name, phone, email, state, "type"
    from t
),
dedupe_three as (
    select distinct on (state, first_name)
        first_name, phone, email, state, "type"
    from t
),
dedupe_four as (
    select distinct on (email) *
    from t
    union
    select distinct on (phone, first_name) *
    from t
    union
    select distinct on (state, first_name) *
    from t
),
dedupe_five as (
    select distinct on (email) *
    from (
        select distinct on (phone, first_name) *
        from (
            select distinct on (state, first_name) *
            from t
        ) foo2
    ) foo
)
select *
from dedupe_five
```

Comment: first remove duplicates based on emails. Next remove duplicates based on phone and first_name. Finally remove duplicates based on state and first_name. You can do each of these separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution.

I first gave `id`s to each row and removed duplicates based on emails, phones and first_names, and states and first_names separately as @topsail advised. At this point, I had three tables. After that, I made a mark in the original table if the original table's row is found in the three deduped tables. Then I outputted any rows in the original table if there are any kind of markers.

It will make sense if you see the output of each step.

Here is the entire query:

```sql
with t as (
select *
    from (
        (
            values ('james', '801xxxxxxx', 'james@gmail.com', 'ca', 'a', 1),
            ('robert', '714xxxxxxx', '', 'ca', 'a', 2),
            ('william', '', 'william@gmail.com', '', 'a', 3),
            ('maria', '1234567890', 'maria@gmail.com', '', 'a', 4),
            ('richard', '', 'richard@gmail.com', '', 'a', 5),
            ('', '', 'james@gmail.com', '', 'b', 1),
            ('maria', '1234567890', '', '', 'b', 2),
            ('robert', '', '', 'ca', 'b', 3)
        )
    ) t (first_name, phone, email, state, "type", id)
),
dedupe_one as (
    select first_name, phone, email, state, type, id
    from (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email order by "type" asc) rn
        from t
        where email is not null and email != ''
    ) foo
    where rn = 1
),
dedupe_two as (
    select first_name, phone, email, state, type, id
    from (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phone, first_name order by "type" asc) rn
        from t
        where phone is not null and phone != '' and first_name is not null and first_name != ''
    ) foo
    where rn = 1
),
dedupe_three as (
    select first_name, phone, email, state, type, id
    from (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state, first_name order by "type" asc) rn
        from t
        where state is not null and state != '' and first_name is not null and first_name != ''
    ) foo
    where rn = 1
),
marked_table as (
    select t.*,
        exists (
            select 1
            from dedupe_one
            where t.id=dedupe_one.id and t."type"=dedupe_one."type"
        ) as mark_one,
        exists (
            select 1
            from dedupe_two
            where t.id=dedupe_two.id and t."type"=dedupe_two."type"
        ) as mark_two,
        exists (
            select 1
            from dedupe_three
            where t.id=dedupe_three.id and t."type"=dedupe_three."type"
        ) as mark_three
    from t
),
final_table as (
    select *
    from marked_table
    where mark_one = true or mark_two = true or mark_three = True
)
select *
from final_table
```

`dedupe_one`:
[image]

`dedupe_two`:
[image]

`dedupe_three`:
[image]

`marked_table`:
[image]

`final_table`:
[image]

I don't think my solution is the most efficient or elegant way of solving my problem. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.